# Embedding of mutually dependent structures/interfaces

Tags: go, interface, structure, embedding

I have 3 structures that are similar about 70%. So I'd like to extract some common part and create some extensions with specific methods and fields.

Final structure will work as follows:

1. method `.Start()` from `Common` is called
2. `Start()` calls method `.Name()` from specific part the latter return a string
3. the returned result is being processed in `(*Common).Process()`, sometimes it should call specific's `Format()`
4. But! Specific part have to call Common part's method, for example `GetVerbosity()`

Like this:

```
package common

type Common struct {
     Specificer 
}

func (c *Common) Start() {
     ...
     name := Specific.Name()
}

func (c *Common) GetVerbosity() {...}

type Specificer interface {
    Name() string
    Format() string
}
```

And specific part:

```
package specific1

// should implement common.Specificer interface
type Specific1 struct {
    // unexported fields
}

func (s *Specific1) Name() string {...}
func (s *Specific1) Format() string {
   // How to call it???
   Common.Method() 
}
```

This is similar to some frameworks - when another code calls your code, and also you call it's code.

How to implement this better? And how to create new structures?
I tried:

1. Embed `Specific` to `Common`, and  embed vise versa:

   ```
   type Common struct {
       Specificer
   }

   type Specific1 struct {
      common.Common
      ...
   }

   // But this is little bit insane:
   func NewSpecific1() *common.Common {
       var s = Specific1{}
       return &common.Common{Specificer: &s}
   }
   ```
2. Define 2 interfaces: `Commoner` and `Specificer`. And combined interface:

   ```
   package common
   type CommonSpecificer interface {
      Commoner
      Specificer
   }

   type Common struct {...}  // implements all the methods from Commoner

   func New() *Common {...}


   //////
   package specific1

   type Specific1 struct  { // implements all the methods from common.Specificer
      Common
      ...
   }  

   func NewSpecific1() *Specific1 {
     c := common.NewCommon(...)
     s := &Specific1{Common: c}
     return s
   }
   ```

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is inheritance, which is deliberately, consciously and by design not supported in go for reasons that can be googled. It can be done, but there is a little messiness involved. However, there's a lot of go code out there and not much of it finds the need to do this so there's probably an alternative approach to solving the problem that would be better or at least more idiomatic. I find that what that solution would be depends on understanding the problem better - different constraints lead to different answers/approaches.

Comment: Option `1.` is fine, the only "insane" thing about it is that you're returning `Common` from a function called `NewSpecific1`, and you're not setting `Common`'s `Specifier`, why? You should return `Specific1` instead. Also this does not seem to require embedding, not that you can't use it, but it will work without it just as well.

Comment: E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/GYuKrg_Luuu

Comment: @GilesW, thank you for the reply. I thought about inheritance, but it's not good in Go. I'd like to make it idiomatically. I feel this task fits Go very well, but the problem is mutual dependency. I'll make more descriptive explanation little later.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you. Thing `foo.Common.Specific = foo` is very interesting, but seems strange a little bit. What if there will be more interfaces? If they are in different packages, move type declarations to 3rd package?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I don't think there's anything strange here, the types have a circular dependency, how else would you express it?

Comment: @mkopriva I also can't find better way :) I think of some sort of embedding to one bigger so so they could find methods on the same level. But if initial structures don't have methods from each other they can't reference them at compile-time.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky how you structure your code, whether you have a package specifically for type declarions only or not, is up to you, just make sure it compiles.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky keep in mind that generally it's a good idea to follow the single responsibility principle. Something "bigger" sounds like you may be trying to do more than just one thing with that...

Comment: One other observation on the question - if the methods added by the specific type are not common (since the common functionality is in the type common), how can they be satisfied by the same interface Specifier? And if they are different then the specific will have to embed the common, not the other way around. But if the methods on each specific type component are different how would the methods in the common type be calling them without type switching? See where the confusion is?

Comment: @GilesW It's quite possible. If you have the same logics and different adapters to very similar resources.

Comment: @mkopriva, yes, I want the same thing: logics in one structure and some adapters to slight modifications in specific structures.